# Animated component not working with react-native-web

Tags: react-native, react-native-web

I have the simplest app/animation set up (below). When I setup a listener on `val`, it appears to be properly changing from 1 to 0. However on the screen, none of this is reflected. "Hello World" does not disappear, ever. If I force a re-render (by adding and updating a state variable), then it will reflect the current value of `val`. Of course, I shouldn't have to force a re-render to see the effects of an animated value changing. I am at my wits end, any help would be greatly appreciated.

App.tsx:

```
// @ts-ignore-next-line
import { View, Animated, Text } from 'react-native';
import React, { FunctionComponent, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const App:FunctionComponent<{}> = () => {
  const val = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;
  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(val, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 1000,
      useNativeDriver: false
    }).start() 
  }, [])

  return (
    <View style={{height: "100%", width: "100%"}}>
      <Animated.View style={{opacity: val}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 50}}>
          Hello world
        </Text>
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Here is my webpack.config.js as well:

```
module.exports = {
  entry : {
    index: './src/index.tsx'
  },
  module : {
    rules : [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        resolve: {
          extensions: ['.web.js', '.ts', '.js', '.tsx', '.jsx'],
        },
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-react"],
            plugins: ['react-native-web'],
          }
        }
      },
      // Typescript loader
      {
         test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
         resolve: {
           extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.tsx', '.jsx'],
         },
         exclude: /node_modules/,
         use: ["ts-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: "html-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.ttf$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  
  resolve: {
    alias: {
        'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
        '../Utilities/Platform': 'react-native-web/dist/exports/Platform',
        '../../Utilities/Platform': 'react-native-web/dist/exports/Platform',
        './Platform': 'react-native-web/dist/exports/Platform',
        'react-native-linear-gradient': 'react-native-web-linear-gradient',
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was because my `index.js` was using

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

instead of

```
import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";

AppRegistry.registerComponent("App", () => App);

AppRegistry.runApplication("App", {
  rootTag: document.getElementById("root")
});
```